# check that user has sucessfully logged in with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I'm writing a bunch of automated tests using selenium and one of the tests requires user authentication. After entering user's credentials (email and password) I need to wait for the process of authentication to complete. So basically it boils down to waiting for the server to respond with an Auth cookie. 
But how do I get it?

I tried searching on the Internet but didn't find anything that answers that question. If I do `driver.get_cookies()` it returns a whole bunch of them, which one of them should I use then?

Comment: Are u heavily dependent on response cookie for validation ? or Are u open for any alternate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
driver.manage().getCookies();
```

will provide Set of cookies used or available at that instance. You have to cross check which cookie is responsible for what and use it.

As knows `driver.manage().addCookie(arg0)`  is used to add required cookies, if you what get required cookies then `driver.manage().getCookieNamed(arg0)`

Comment: In Python Webdriver instance has no such attribute as `manage`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Well yeah eventually I've solved it by getting all the cookies with the `get_cookies` (aka `getCookies` in Java) method and checking if the returned list contains the one I'm looking for. My problem was that I didn't quite understand which one to search for but after looking deeper into the server response I was able to figure it out.